# PPT , PDF and MP4 Documents Links not opening / working MS Teams Personal Tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have created the Personal Tabs in MS Teams to show the Corporate SharePoint Portal which contains Quick Links, latest Training Video web-part which has MP4, PDF, and PPTX links.

But unable to open/download the PPTX, PDF, and MP4 documents links in Teams (both desktop version and Web app). But if you try the Corporate SharePoint site URL in the browser, the links were accessible - working fine.

Could you please guide us to resolve this issue,

Comment: You need to upload the PDF in SPO library through Teams, when you upload the PDF in Teams it will generate a default SharePoint pdf URL from for your SPO folder, if you give that URL in Tab or Task Module, it should work. Follow these steps for more clarification:
1. Upload your pdf in Teams
2. Once it uploaded, copy the PDF URL (This URL will be SPO Url linked with your teams)
3. Give the same URL to Tab or Task module

Comment: Thanks Gousia, the PPTX is working fine but teams url is not generated for MP4. Could you please help me out in this scenario ?

Comment: Could you please share the issue you are seeing with mp4?

Comment: mp4 , pptx and other documents in Personal tabs in Teams are not clickable.